# Submit button to affect multiple files

Tags: php, jquery

**Current Situation:**

So, for an article page (`article.php`), I have 2 different sections (title, content), which are hooked to the article page from their own php files (Title is pulled from `title.php` while content is pulled from `content.php`).

Now, I added an ability for the author to edit the title and content on the article which they need to press `submit` button in order save the change.

**Problem**

After editing, the author needs to press "Submit" button in order to update the data.
However, when I put the "submit" button in either `title.php` or `content.php`, only the corresponding section is updated while the other is unchanged (for example, if I have this `submit` button in the `title.php` then only `title` is edited).

If I put the button in the `article.php` then of course neither the title nor content gets updated.

**Here is the mark up:**

Article.php:

```
<div class="article">
  <?php do_action ('article_summary'); ?>
</div>
```

Title.php (with the `submit` button, which only updates the title)

```
<form role="form" method="post">                    
    <div class="edit_title">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
        <?php post_input_box( $post_id, 'post_title', array( 'placeholder' => 'Article title..', 'value' => $post->post_title ) ); ?>
        <div class="update-button-wrap">
            <input type="submit" name="update_product" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update', 'site' ); ?>"/>
        </div>  
    </div>                  
</form>
```

Content.php

```
<form role="form" method="post">                    
    <div class="edit_content">
        <?php post_input_box( $post_id, 'post_content', array( 'placeholder' => 'Short description..', 'value' => $post->post_content ), 'textarea' ); ?>
    </div>                      
</form>
```

Does anyone know how the submit button can save both title and content that are in two different files?

Thanks bunch!

Comment: You could either use ajax to submit one of the forms first, and then on success submit the other. Or you could use javascript/jquery to merge the values of both forms into one form to submit all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a super-button (pattent pending) that presses all them other buttons for ye...

```
<button type='button' onclick="$('[type="submit"]').click()">Submit</button>
```

Since its type button, it won't submit itself. Replace each submit button with this. I mean, leave the original buttons there, but style them with

```
button[type="submit"] { display:none }
```