# Updating different forms at the same time

Tags: php, jquery

**Current Situation**

So, this is a follow up question from my previous question ([Submit button to affect multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905297/submit-button-to-affect-multiple-files/30905375?noredirect=1#comment49849302_30905375))

The approach was good in terms of how to "click" multiple buttons together by using a "super-button" (patent pending) by @oMiKeY. It does what it is supposed to do, clicking all buttons.

The **mark up** is the following:

**Title.php**

```
    <form role="form" method="post">                    
        <div class="edit_title">
             <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
             <?php post_input_box( $post_id, 'post_title', array( 'placeholder' => 'Article title..', 'value' => $post->post_title ) ); ?>
            <div class="update-button-wrap">
                 <input id="save_button" type="submit" name="update_product" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update', 'site' ); ?>"/>
            </div>  
        </div>                  
    </form>
```

**Content.php**

```
 <form role="form" method="post">                   
        <div class="edit_content">
            <?php post_input_box( $post_id, 'post_content', array( 'placeholder' => 'Short description..', 'value' => $post->post_content ), 'textarea' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="update-button-wrap">
            <input id="save_button" type="submit" name="update_product" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update', 'site' ); ?>"/>
        </div>                          
</form>
```

**Article.php**

```
<button type='button' onclick="$('[type="submit"]').click()">Submit</button>
```

**Problem**

So, when the "Submit" button is clicked, both buttons in each `title.php` and `content.php` are also clicked (ie. in regards to clicking buttons, it works fine). However, because two `forms` are simultaneously clicked, only the second one is updated (either content or title) while the first one is ignored, when both data are needed to be updated.

**My approach**

Now, I can merge two files together and have both `title` and `content` within a single form, but that really messes up my overall setup and I heard it is better to have multiple smaller php files for updating and speed than a large one big file.

Or here is my another approach.

In the `article.php`, I will have the `form` and `submit` button while the `title.php` and `content.php` only has the editable forms. Then these two forms are somehow linked to the form in `article.php`, like the image below.

[image]

Do you think the second approach can be achieved or any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use one form in total? Or what about submitting it via ajax?

Comment: yeah, that using one form will make things simpler in general but I will need to change pretty much the overall setup in order to do that. I wanted to avoid doing it :P but if there is no other option, then I will for sure do it. =)

Comment: You can not submit two forms at the same time directly. Either make them one form – or submit them in the background, using AJAX.

Comment: I see. I might just combine them all together into one form :P

Comment: If you know that a certain approach makes the code better or more simple at this point, change it. It might cost you some time to rewrite it but better now then having bigger problems on the moment that your application is even more complex and so more difficult to maintain.

Comment: True. Yeah, I wanted to salvage what I had before. I guess there is no easy way around it. Thanks for the help though =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a global form on article.php and drop the title and content forms (and submit buttons). Every named input inside the global form will be submitted together no matter what php file generated them.

Edit:
**Title.php**

```
<div class="edit_title">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
     <?php post_input_box( $post_id, 'post_title', array( 'placeholder' => 'Article title..', 'value' => $post->post_title ) ); ?>
</div>
```

**Content.php**

```
<div class="edit_content">
    <?php post_input_box( $post_id, 'post_content', array( 'placeholder' => 'Short description..', 'value' => $post->post_content ), 'textarea' ); ?>
</div>
```

**Article.php**

```
<form role="form" method="post">
<?php include "Title.php"; include "Content.php"; ?>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Option 2:**
Alternatively you could use some sort of functionality that allows you to create forms only once, even if you have "inner forms". This way Title.php and Content.php would also work as standalone code snippets.

```
$formDeep = 0;
function openForm() {
    global $formDeep;
    if ($formDeep == 0) {
        echo "<form role=\"form\" method=\"post\">";
    }
    $formDeep++;
}

function closeForm() {
    global $formDeep;
    $formDeep--;
    if ($formDeep == 0) {
        echo "</form>";
    }
}
```

**Title.php**

```
<?php openForm(); ?>
<div class="edit_title">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
     <?php post_input_box( $post_id, 'post_title', array( 'placeholder' => 'Article title..', 'value' => $post->post_title ) ); ?>
</div>
<?php closeForm(); ?>
```

**Content.php**

```
<?php openForm(); ?>
<div class="edit_content">
    <?php post_input_box( $post_id, 'post_content', array( 'placeholder' => 'Short description..', 'value' => $post->post_content ), 'textarea' ); ?>
</div>
<?php closeForm(); ?>
```

**Article.php**

```
<?php openForm(); ?>
<?php include "Title.php"; include "Content.php"; ?>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
<?php closeForm(); ?>
```

Comment: hmm, I am not sure if I understand what you mean. So, you are saying that the `article-form` have all the `title-form`, `content-form` and `submit-button` (so, pretty much, combine all the forms into one form, like my first approach). Am I understanding you correctly? thanks

Comment: Edited for clarification. I didn't merge the files because I assume you use them elsewhere. :)

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I am going to give it a try and get back to you on that one. I see the logic behind it. =)

Comment: Also see additional suggestion.